# iCloud save support in Grand Theft Auto: Vice City

Tags: iphone, ipad, icloud, ipod-touch, games

I've been playing on my iPhone and iPad, and it appears that in order to do a "cloud save", I need to actually find a save point on one device and then do a save. Then, on my other device I need to manually load that save.

I was hoping this would be a little more automatic - is there something I'm doing wrong? I'd expect the game to just pick up where I left off on the other device.

Comment: No you are doing it correctly. GTA has always used "save points" as opposed to "auto-save", which means that in order for anything to get up to the cloud, you have to go to a save point. As far as auto-resuming on the other device, that seems to just be a design decision.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is how it GTA operates. Both Vice City and San Andreas iOS version of it. I've always wondered whether the game keeps some of the game save data in Game Center, iCloud or to a app-native cloud system.